# Difference in result while using len() function and index with np.random.permutation

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This is the code I tried:

```
np.random.seed(1)

dc_listings = dc_listings.loc[np.random.permutation(len(dc_listings))]
```

When I use the `len()` function, I get a static dataframe but when I use `dc_listings.loc[np.random.permutation(dc_listings.index)]`, I get different dataframes even after setting `random.seed()`.

Please explain?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the seed before every time you call the `np.random.permutation()`:

```
np.random.seed(1)
dc_listings = dc_listings.loc[np.random.permutation(dc_listings.index))]
np.random.seed(1)
dc_listings = dc_listings.loc[np.random.permutation(len(dc_listings))]
```

Doing this will keep the permuations reproducible.